# Find the number of solutions to the equation $f(x)=\ln(α), α>0$ for every possible value of $α$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let f be a continuous function with: $f(x)= e^{-x^2}+3, x<0$ and $f(x)=4-x^2, x\geq0$.
Find the number of solutions to the equation $f(x)=\ln(α), α>0$, for every possible $α$.

My question is, do I have to transform the equation to $e^{f(x)}=α$ and then solve it by creating the $C_f$, or do I just take all the possible values for α straight away, e.g. if  $0<α<1$, then $\ln(a)$ is strictly decreasing and continue like this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question.$$e^{-x^2}+3=\ln{(\alpha)}\iff x=-\sqrt{-\ln{(\ln{(\alpha)}-3)}}\quad(e^3\lt\alpha\lt e^4)$$$$4-x^2=\ln{(\alpha)}\iff x=\sqrt{4-\ln{(\alpha)}}\quad(0\lt\alpha\lt e^4)$$So what can you say about $f(x)=\ln{(\alpha)}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln x$ is bijective from $(0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R},$ is stricty increasing, continuous. To simplify the work, set $B=\ln x.$

If $x>0,$ the function $f(x)= e^{-x^2}+3$ is increasing with range $(3,4].$
Therefore, the equation $e^{-x^2}+3=B$ has exactly one solution if $B\in (3,4]$ and no solution for other values B.
Returning to $\alpha,$ we will solve $$3 <\ln \alpha \leq 4.$$ We get $$\alpha \in (e^3,e^4].$$ For these values of $\alpha$ has the equation  $1$ solution, otherwise there is no solution.

---

Can you solve for the second function?